# Android App Crashes when i run this code from the example

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Im running this code with the buildozer but every time i click on the take picture on my android device the app crashes. The main screen comes up file and the build is okay. I've added extra permissions and and put the requirement for python 2 as well. I have also added the android to the requirements but it still doesn't work.

```
'''
Basic camera example
Default picture is saved as
/sdcard/org.test.cameraexample/enter_file_name_here.jpg
'''

from os import getcwd
from os.path import exists
from os.path import splitext

import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.logger import Logger

from plyer import camera


class CameraDemo(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CameraDemo, self).__init__()
        self.cwd = getcwd() + "/"
        self.ids.path_label.text = self.cwd

    def do_capture(self):
        filepath = self.cwd + self.ids.filename_text.text
        ext = splitext(filepath)[-1].lower()

        if(exists(filepath)):
            popup = MsgPopup("Picture with this name already exists!")
            popup.open()
            return False

        try:
            camera.take_picture(filename=filepath,
                                on_complete=self.camera_callback)
        except NotImplementedError:
            popup = MsgPopup(
                "This feature has not yet been implemented for this platform.")
            popup.open()

    def camera_callback(self, filepath):
        if(exists(filepath)):
            popup = MsgPopup("Picture saved!")
            popup.open()
        else:
            popup = MsgPopup("Could not save your picture!")
            popup.open()


class CameraDemoApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CameraDemoApp, self).__init__()
        self.demo = None

    def build(self):
        self.demo = CameraDemo()
        return self.demo

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


class MsgPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(MsgPopup, self).__init__()
        self.ids.message_label.text = msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CameraDemoApp().run()
```

My Buildozer file is as follows, but im not sure what my permissions and info shoul look like.

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Kivy Camera Example

# (str) Package name
package.name = cameraexample

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
# version.regex = __version__ = '(.*)'
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 1.0

# (list) Application requirements 
# android library is also required to run this app on Android platform
# for android device -> requirements = plyer,kivy,android
requirements = plyer,kivy,python2

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
# android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = 

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters = 

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
# 
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#     [app]
#     source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns]
#     license
#     data/audio/*.wav
#     data/images/original/*
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#     [app@demo]
#     title = My Application (demo)
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#     images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#     buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: I suspect you will need permisions: `android.permissions = CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Hi John i have added the permissions but it still crashes...I understand it

Comment: I dont understand it??

Comment: Try `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt 2>&1` (if you are running `Bash`) to get a log of what is happening. Requires having your `Android` device connected.

Comment: Thanks John, im running a (Ubunu 18) virtual machine on windows 7, do you know how i link them to get the report?

Comment: On Ubuntu, you just connect it with a USB cable. You may need to turn on `Developer Options` and `USB debugging` under `settings` on your Android device.